# How do I configure my Electron app with Webpack for production?

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server

This is my `webpack.config.js` file

I've just done a build with `electron-packager` for the first time and realized that I'm pointing only the `devServer` in here.

I've been doing some research but haven't found much that's helpful. I'd love some help as to setting up my Webpack config to hit my production server.

**My main issue is I don't really know where to start, i.e. what's important in a webpack prod config vs a dev config. Is it as simple as providing an alternate URL is different bundling of files?**

Thanks!

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './scripts/app.js']
  },

  output: {
    // path: './public/built',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/built'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/built/'
  },

  devServer: {
    // contentBase: './public',
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/built/'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            enforce: "pre",
            loader: "eslint-loader",
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-3']
            }
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
        { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'},
        { test: /\.(ttf|eot|otf|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(new RegExp("^(fs|ipc)$")),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
            eslint: {
                failOnWarning: false,
                failOnError: true
            }
        }
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: A good example may be to look at this boilerplate https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

Comment: Thanks. Is it standard to have multiple webpack config files? One for dev and one for prod?

Comment: It has been on the projects that I've worked on. But I don't think it's a requirement.

Comment: I have a pretty simple app at this point, I'd like to avoid it if possible, maybe refactor to 2 later

Comment: The following boilerplate does not even use webpack, something that you could consider https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate

Comment: I appreciate the links. I guess what I don't understand is what exactly I need to do to make this production-ready? Is it just an alternate URL or do I need to handle/bundle/export my files differently?

Comment: You are going to want a different URL and you do not need 'webpack/hot/dev-server' or devServer. Just glancing at it.

Comment: Would you mind posting an answer with some example code with keys and values as to how to get this working? That would be the most helpful to me and people who come across this in the future. Thanks for all of your help Xotic

Comment: Depending on what you are using webpack for, you could also just use [electron compile](https://github.com/electron/electron-compile) and not even have to worry about webpack.

Comment: I don't think that I can give a simple and definitive (a good) answer to the question. My advice would be to use a known boilerplate for your project.

Comment: @BertEvans Thanks for the link. I'm not sure what I'm using webpack for honestly, it's my first project using it. I just figured I had to